# Use inkscape to optimize SVG from command line

Tags: svg, command-line, inkscape

In `inkscape` you can save an SVG images as an optimized SVG. See for example [this](https://superuser.com/q/1256265) SO question.

Is it possible to use this feature to optimize an SVG image using the command line only?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use Scour directly: https://github.com/scour-project/scour (this is what Inkscape hooks into with the 'Save as ... > Optimized SVG' dialog).